# aiohttp - exception ignored message

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm running the following code which makes 5 requests via aiohttp:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

def fetch_page(url, idx):
    try:
        url = 'http://google.com'
        response = yield from aiohttp.request('GET', url)

        print(response.status)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def main():
    try:
        url = 'http://google.com'
        urls = [url] * 5

        coros = []
        for idx, url in enumerate(urls):
            coros.append(asyncio.Task(fetch_page(url, idx)))

        yield from asyncio.gather(*coros)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Output:

```
200
200
200
200
200
Exception ignored in: Exception ignored in: Exception ignored in: Exception ignored in: Exception ignored in:
```

Note: There is no additional information as to what/where the exception is.

What's causing this and are there any tips to debug it?

Comment: Note that wrapping whole functions in `try: ... except Exception` is not best practice. What are you running this code *in* - is the *"Exception ignored"* message from your IDE?

Comment: I added those to try to catch the error - the "Exception ignored" is actually printed without the `try... except` present. I'm thinking that something in `aiohttp` or `asyncio` is muting out the exceptions. I'm running this in a script executed via terminal in Python 3.4.

Comment: Looks like this might be related to [this python bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue22836). I'm not sure why an unraisable exception is occurring in the first place, though; I can't reproduce it on my system.

Comment: @okoboko Also see the comments at the end of [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue23548) where this same error is mentioned when exiting an `asyncio` application. Are you using Python 3.4.3?

Comment: Hmm, that's strange indeed. I'm using 3.5.0a1. Glad it appears to be unrelated to my code.

Comment: @okoboko Well, according to the comments it probably means there's a task that isn't complete at the end of your program, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Try adding `response.close()` at the end of `fetch_page`, and `loop.close()` after the `loop.run_until_complete(..)` line, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @dano `response.close()` fixed it. Will you add that as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @dano Even I am facing the same issue though I am not using asyncio or aiohttp. It occurs when I am trying to allocate a class instance to a dictionary as a value to an integer key. Any idea how to stop getting the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, but it seems that leaving the `aiohttp.ClientResponse` object open is causing an unraisable exception to be thrown when the interpreter exits. On my system, this results in warnings like this, rather than "Exception ignored in" messages:

```
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket object at 0x7f44fce557a8>
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket object at 0x7f44fce55718>
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket object at 0x7f44fcc24a78>
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket object at 0x7f44fcc248c8>
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket object at 0x7f44fcc24958>
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket object at 0x7f44fcc249e8>
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket object at 0x7f44fcc24b08>
```

In any case, you can fix it by explicitly closing the `ClientResponse` object at the end of `fetch_objects`, by calling `response.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but using the `Context` class and its method `request`, you have to not forget to call `shutdown()` method on your Context object at the end to avoid the `Exception ignored in:` message.
As the shutdown method is async and I was using python 3.4 the call is done using `yield from`.